# SQL Server error log file, missing some dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 and I noticed some missing dates from my SQL server error log files.

Example I am missing dates from 13-21 Jan 2011? Where is it.... and I have all the dates before and after.

I check the Win event file - Security and see that there was activity on 19 Jan and I know that they were connecting to SQL but SQL log didn't record it or it did?....

Comment: Define 'log file'. Audit log? System event log? Database log?

Comment: Sorry, I mean System event log file.....

Answer (score 0):

The [error] log files are created stamped at the date SQL Server service started, they just keep adding to the same file instead of creating one for each date.

Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885.aspx

> A new error log is created each time an instance of SQL Server is started, although the sp_cycle_errorlog system stored procedure can be used to cycle the error log files without having to restart the instance of SQL Server.

Comment: ok but I have all the archive from a month ago for every day ... and there was only one restart of the server and it is the one... but how come that n the Win Server Security log people were loggin in and using SQL data... it is a mistery to me....

Comment: What SQL Server does is clear, but I am not sure why you would see a new .log file each day - unless the machine or SQL Server was restarted every day (scheduled task? backup?) or there is a process to fire sp_cycle_errorlog

Comment: Well I monitor the the server every day and of course doing on that server other things...reporting, replication etc....onlong the way I also check the log file... that logfile shows me who connected succes. and failed logins etc...But I also noticed something else...

Comment: It happened two time not only ones...I have log up to 16 Dec 2010 and then NOTHING then 13 Jan 11 one log entry... from 13 -21 NOTHING again!!! Only thing that is interesting is the lag log entries and that is:                                                                  Message
The SQL Network Interface library could not deregister the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x45b, state: 4. Administrator should deregister this SPN manually to avoid client authentication errors.

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to get the answer. It was a DNS issue which is sorted out. Thanks